# Decompress Mercurial repository files

Tags: mercurial

I created a repository and synchronized it with a remote repository.

The files are compressed and each has an (i) extension.

I want to extract the files to a new folder (not repository) with decompressing them and with their original name as I see them on the web browsing on Google code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you do `hg clone <remoteRepoPath> <localPath>` to do that, which automatically updates the working directory.

Since you did an `hg init` and then `hg pull` from the remote repo, you need to do `hg update` and it will fill the working directory with the actual files.

All those `.i` files under the `.hg` directory are the repository's storage and indexes and such. Very rarely does anybody mess with those manually. Most of the time the only thing people touch under the `.hg` directory is the `hgrc` file and patch queues.